# Accessing the this context in an AJAX call that is not the callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, this

I have an AJAX call, where I use a variable bound to `this` in my URL call. I also need this in the callback.

Initially I was using the var `_that = this` pattern, but that didn't pass code review. I threw in the `context: this`, but unsure if it works on that second link, where I need to actually access this or if it's only available in the callback.

#### Question:

What is the cleanest approach for accessing the `this` context variable to use in the `url` param and also the callback?

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/search/".concat(_this.options.modelId),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'PUT',
        data: JSON.stringify(templatePerms),
        context: this,
        success: function(data) {
            this.message('Success!', 'Updated', 'success');
            this.cleanup();
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you save it in `context` then you would access it via `this.context`.  A better question would be:  Why didn't `var _that = this;` pass code review?  That is a fairly standard practice.

Comment: As a side note, if you are building the url then I would probably set it in a variable and just use the variable rather than doing it inline with the `_this.options` reference.  But, that is largely preference/style.

Comment: Interesting the `_that` doesn't pass code review but the misuse of `concat()` does pass. Question should be about the code review!

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. I actually agree that concat() is oddly used here, not really sure why I chose that route. Bunch of backend guys here writing frontend code.

Comment: "*didn't pass code review*" - surely your reviewer told you which alternative is preferred. If he didn't, ask him - not us.

Comment: In the url, you definitely should be using standard `this`, not `_that` or `_this` or any workaround.

Comment: @Bergi He did and he said use context.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an extra variable (e.g. `_this`), utilize [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) passing `this` as the [*`thisArg`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Parameters):

```
success: function(data) {
    this.message('Success!', 'Updated', 'success');
    this.cleanup();
}.bind(this)
```

Comment: Yes, but can this still be used outside the callback in the AJAX function? That is ultimately my question.

Comment: My initial answer is _yes_ but based on your question there may be other issues here... I would need to see more code than just the `$.ajax()` call...

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
  this.options = {};
    this.options.modelId = '1';
    this.doIt();
  }

  doIt() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + this.options.modelId,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      type: 'PUT'
    })
    .then(data=>this.success.call(this, data));
  }

  success(data) {
    this.message(data);
  }

  message(msg) {
    alert(msg.id);
  }

}
new Test();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```